# How can I install antlr3c development files on Fedora?

Tags: fedora, antlr3, linphone

I am trying to build an Android application based on Linphone library. When I run the top-level Makefile it cannot resolve all dependencies. The belle-sip sublibrary asks for antlr3c component
(`configure: error: Could not find antlr3 development files. Please install antlr3 version > 3.2 (libantlr3c-dev on debian/ubuntu systems)`) but I just can't manage to find it and install on my system. I have already installed antrl3, I just miss the C version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ dnf search antlr3
Last metadata expiration check performed 2 days, 18:57:31 ago on Sat Mar  5 11:56:16 2016.
============================= N/S Matched: antlr3 ==============================
antlr3-javadoc.noarch : API documentation for antlr3
antlr3-C.i686 : C run-time support for ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr3-C.x86_64 : C run-time support for ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr3-java.noarch : Java run-time support for ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr3-tool.noarch : ANother Tool for Language Recognition
antlr32-java.noarch : Java run-time support for ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr32-tool.noarch : Command line tool for creating ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr3-C-docs.noarch : API documentation for the C run-time support for
                     : ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr3-C-devel.i686 : Header files for the C bindings for ANTLR-generated
                    : parsers
antlr3-C-devel.x86_64 : Header files for the C bindings for ANTLR-generated
                      : parsers
antlr32-javadoc.noarch : API documentation for ANTLR
antlr3-C++-devel.i686 : C++ runtime support for ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr3-C++-devel.x86_64 : C++ runtime support for ANTLR-generated parsers
antlr3-javascript.noarch : Javascript run-time support for ANTLR-generated
                         : parsers
antlr32-maven-plugin.noarch : Maven plug-in for creating ANTLR-generated parsers
```

Looks like `antlr3-C-devel` is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Ok I did not know the dnf command, it seems really useful! Of course, antlr3 is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @mattdm!